# How to get idevaffiliate user_id from idevafiliate referral link in joomla 3

Tags: php, integration, joomla3.0

I'm using idevaffiliate referral URL for redirecting on Joomla site.

For eg. the refrral link for idevaffiliate

```
localhost/iaji/idevaffiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=100
```

I want to get the affiliate user id in Joomla. Anybody know s the integration of idevaffiliate with Joomla 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any variables passed to joomla using jinput - [http://docs.joomla.org/API17:JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/API17%3aJInput)

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$foo = $jinput->get('nameyofyourvar', '0', null);
```

I wouldn't call it "id", though, as that may well conflict with Joomla's own variables.

Comment: For Idevaffiliate integration with joomla.
You need to construct your own referral link, which can redirect to the new joomla user registration form.
After registration you can use the user details & call the iDevAffiliate API for new account creation with additional 'tier' parameter attached to it.
tier parameter is nothing but the parent user iDevaffiliate user_id.
So that you easily create new user in Idevaffiliate along with the tier connection using Joomla.